# How to ignore creating first data of an array while creating a table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, csv, html-table

How to ignore first data of an array while making a table? in my case, I'm creating a page for uploading a `csv file` from my local directory and then creating a table to display the data. I have made the code and work perfectly. but I didn't want to create the 1st row of the array data into my table.

I don't know how to do that. Here is my code for uploading the `csv file` and creating the table

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    $('#submit-file').on("click",function(e){
  if ($('#files').val()== "")
  {
   alert("Anda Harus Memasukkan File Terlebih Dahulu");
  }
  else{
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#files').parse({
   config: {
    delimiter: "",
    complete: displayHTMLTable,
   },
   before: function(file, inputElem)
   {
    //console.log("Parsing file...", file);
   },
   error: function(err, file)
   {
    //console.log("ERROR:", err, file);
   },
   complete: function()
   {
    //console.log("Done with all files");
   }
  });
  }
    });
 
 function displayHTMLTable(results){
  var table = "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
  var data = results.data;
  var size = -1;
  for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   table+= "<tr>";
   var row = data[i]; 
   var cells = row.join(",").split(",");
   if (cells.length < size) continue;
         else if (cells.length >  size) size = cells.length;
   for(j=0;j<cells.length;j++){
    
    table+= "<td>";
    table+= cells[j];
    table+= "</td>";
   }
   table+= "</tr>";
  }
  table+= "</table>";
  $("#parsed_csv_list").html(table);
 } 
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.3.5/papaparse.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="padding:5px 5px; margin-left:5px">
 <div class="well" style="width:70%">
  <div class="row">
  <form class="form-inline">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="files">Upload File Data :</label>
     <input type="file" id="files"  class="form-control" accept=".csv" required />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" id="submit-file" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
             
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   
   <div id="parsed_csv_list" class="panel-body table-responsive" style="width:800px">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loop that iterates through your data array, simply start at index 1 instead of index 0.

```
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
     ^^^^^^^^^
```

That will skip over the first entry of the array entirely.

Comment: wow... it work T_T
it just change the iterate only T_T
thx @ABabin